React Native iOS Build Error: PhaseScriptExecution Failed with a nonzero exit code
I'm encountering an issue while building my React Native project for iOS in Xcode. The build fails with the following error
React-rncore Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
I’m using:
React Native version: 0.72.4
Xcode version: 16.1 (16B40)
macOS version: 15.1.1 (24B91)
